# How to receive data multiple times from a single client TCP c#

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, server, client

I am trying to listen for the client sending data multiple times. I do not know how to make the server listen to the client when the data is sent by the client a second time. For now i can send data by the client multiple times but the server will only accept the client data once. Please help.

Client

```
//the client
    private TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    //constructor
    public ClientConnect(string Ip, int Port)
    {
        IP = Ip;
        PORT = Port;
    }
    //write the data to the server
    public void Connect(byte[] clientId)
    {
        //try to connect to the server
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), PORT));
                    break;
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect to the server...");
                    //pass if the connection failed
                }
            }
            client.GetStream().Write(clientId, 0, (int)clientId.Length);
        });
        t.Start();
    }
    public void SendData(byte[] data)
    {
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() => {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.GetStream().Write(data, 0, (int)data.Length);
                    break;
                }
                catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    //pass
                }
            }
        });
        t2.Start();
    }
```

Server:

```
while (true)
            {
                //Listen for a potential client
                TcpClient client = tcpServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine(client);

                Console.WriteLine("Client connection accepted from " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint + ".");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
                byte[] buffer2 = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead).ToArray();

                //do something with the data 
            }
```

Comment: Is it possible that server crashes after it receives first chunk of data?

Comment: no i don't get any errors. The server first listens for any possible client to be accepted and then after the client made the connection and it run the code it starts listening for another client